# How do I insert a chunk of code every time my while loops fetches some data from my database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a table in my database. I use a while loop to traverse them. and make a HTML div with that fetched data. I used LIMIT 10 because entries in posts will keep changing as users will keep inserting posts into the table

```
$get_ids=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id LIMIT 10");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($get_ids)){
            $sm=$row['message'];
            echo "<div>".$sm"</div>";
}
```

What i want to know is how do i use jquery to make this script insert these 10 divs into my DOM every 1 second or so. Help please URGENT!!!!

Comment: Read http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ and maybe http://api.jquery.com/html/ too. Good documentation and many examples are provided there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to google for some jquery & php webservice examples. Basically you should do something like this:

```
//Javascript function which fetches the single data as J.D.Smith suggested
function getHtml()
{
   $.get({
      'url': 'Address of your php webservice',
      'success': function(data) {
           $("#content").html($("#content").html() + data);   //Append html to your page
       }
   });
}

//Call the function every 10 sec, place it in $(document).ready() or anything else you use
window.setTimeout(function () {
        getHtml();
    }, 10000);
```

This code is more to be illustrative sample than working code

Answer (score 1):

You'd put that code in a separate file (for example: divfill.php) and then use something like this

```
$.get({
    'url': 'divfill.php',
    'success': function(data) {
       $("#content").html($("#content").html() + data);
    }
});
```

Comment: PHP code is run only once: when the server sends the page to the client. You can, in theory, make it so that the page just continuously loads. However you would be restricted to adding code to the bottom of your HTML file. Does it work? Yea, but not very well. I'd highly recommend not attempting something like that and instead using AJAX.

Comment: Ok i intend to use ajax. That is what i am asking basically. Since im not a jquery guru, can you give a hint or a short snippet on how this should be done

Comment: Put my above code in a function (and replace #content with whatever identifier you need). Then, use [window.setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) to run the function every 1 second.

Comment: function getposts(){
 $.get({
    'url': 'php/sortest.php',
    'success': function(data) {
       $(".post-container").html($(".post-container").html() + data);
    }
 });
 }
 window.setInterval(getposts, 1000);

But doesnot work

Comment: That looks like it *should* work to me, though I've never tried it before so I can't say for certain.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have added the following method in my js file,

```
    //call the target function after 250 ms
function async(targetFn, callback) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        targetFn();
        callback();
    }, 250);
}
```

And, I call this function as shown below,

```
async(BindValuesInLookup, function () {
         BuildGrid()
         GetInfo();
    });
```

BindValuesInLookup is the target function. It gets fired after 250ms. Once it is done, the callback functons will be executed. So you can use this functionality in the loop and increase the timeout to 1000 (1 sec).

Thanks,
Vim

Comment: Can you please explain the whole jquery function